# Is there any way to listen to the keyboard back button using ionic?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I need to listen to the back button to run a certain function but the usual `platform.registerBackButtonAction()` won't work when I've got an open keyboard.

[image: soft keyboard with red frame around back button]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because it's not a back button event when the keyboard is open, you'll need the [Keyboard plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/) and use the `onKeyboardHide()` subscribing to the event, so when you press the button to hide the keyboard a event is fired.

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard'; // import it

construtor(public keyboard: Keyboard){
  keybard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(event =>{
    // DO YOUR STUFF
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, keyboard events are not getting fired.
Need help on how to handle physical back button click when the keypad is open

Comment: This looks like a question instead of an answer, please consider posted a new question for help with your issue.